# Translate "I listened to... and all I got was this t-shirt" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I have a musical project I've been working on called *Instruments of Ruin* (it's instrumental, so the name is a play on that). I want to make shirts for it that have the phrase, "I listened to Instruments of Ruin and all I got was this t-shirt".

I was thinking of something along the lines of this (possibly substituting *sed* for *et*):

> Ad Instrumenti Ruinarum audiebam et solum haec tunicam dabar

Does this make sense, or is there a better way to say it?

Comment: 1. You probably want to put all this in a past tense; 2. *audeo* means "to dare." You want *audio*. Others will chime in with more specific suggestions.

Comment: Ahh, thanks! _Audeo_ was a typo, but tenses are still confusing to me. I'll make an update with what I think it is.

Comment: I don't understand your play with words?

Comment: Where I live a famous actress said once: Never, ever place/use phrases from a language you don't know into a t-shirt you pretend to wear! She had visited an Islamic place for a movie festival in the 70's and he and her husband innocently accepted a courtesy gift: a pair of t-shirts with word in a language that was not Arabic, but made lots of sense for some people around. Bad trip, she said!

Comment: Welcome, @love_latin. Unfortunately, I had to convert your "answer" to a comment since it doesn't actually attempt to answer the question. I know you don't have enough "rep" to comment yet, so I did that for you. Answers though have to be on-topic, as it's Q&A style here, not forum discussion. I hope you stick around though and ask/answer some questions yourself!

Comment: @Adam: How do we order the T-shirt?

Comment: @tony I haven't gotten that far with it (I'd like to get the album out first), but when they are available I'll probably add something to my SE profile about the band with a link.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would prefer *auscultare* over *audire*, because it stands for attentive listening. *Audire* is the more general word and would probably not be wrong, though. *Auscultare* stands with the accusative or dative. As Unbrutal Russian points out in a comment, the dative is used when the sense is one of listening and believing, taking heed, doing as told. That does not fit here, so we want the accusative. And as TKR points out, the verb should not be in the imperfect tense. We are presumably talking about a listening event that antecedes (or goes along with) the reception of a t-shirt.

*Instrumentum* is neuter, so you can bet your *infimum thalerum* the plural is going to end in *-a* somehow. In this case, quite simply: *instrumenta*. That would be the accusative; the dative would be *instrumentis*. (At this point I was also going to complain about the plural *ruinarum*, but it turns out that that is quite common classically. So I learned something new today.)

There is nothing wrong with *solum* per se, although it would be a bit more usual to say *ni(hi)l nisi* here. Or, since in English you do not just say “only this t-shirt,” but “all I got etc,” one might prefer a more explicit phrase like *nihil praeterquam*.

*Haec tunicam* should be *hanc tunicam*.

Finally, *dabar* is wrong. I find the imperfect hard to justify here, but there is a more fundamental problem. You see, the recipient with *dare* is in the dative case, the thing given in the accusative. When you turn an active verb passive, the accusative object becomes the subject. The dative object just remains the dative object:

> Tunicam mihi dedit (aliqui) = tunica mihi data est (ab aliquo)

So *dabar* means “I am given” all right, but in the sense that you are the thing that's changing hands. That makes little sense here. But never worry, Latin has your back with the nice word *accipere*.

So in sum I would suggest:

> Instrumenta Ruinarum auscultavi et nihil accepi praeterquam hanc tunicam.

Comment: I'd think *auscultavi* (pf.) would be used here -- it's not a narrative background "I was listening (and then something else happened)", but a discrete action that's part of the main narrative. For the second half I like your *nihil nisi* (more pithy than *praeterquam*) and would suggest moving the verb to the end: *nihil nisi hanc tunicam accepi*. (I wonder if *nec aliquid* would be more idiomatic than *et nihil*, but that's probably overly pedantic.)

Comment: @TKR You are right regarding the tense. *Nec aliquid nisi …* was my first idea, but I (books-) googled and did not find the results convincing, so I took the less adventurous route.

Comment: *auscultāre* with the dative means "to listen to someone and do what you're told"; you want the accusative with a physical act of listening. Otherwise this seems like a solid translation suggestion.

Comment: “*Haec tunicam* should be *hanc*,” reads as though the entire phrase *haec tunicam* would be replaced with just the word *hanc*, but I see in your final suggestion that it’s actually to replace the *haec* in *haec tunicam* with *hanc* and thus yield *hanc tunicam*. I suggest “*Haec tunicam* should be *hanc tunicam*,” as the shortest clarified version, though “The *haec* in *haec tunicam* should be *hanc*,” is perhaps closer to your phrasing.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian you are quite correct, I was unaware of the finer points. A case where [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dausculto) are worlds better than [Georges](http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1913/A/ausculto?hl=dat), by the way.

Comment: @KRyan I thought that was pretty obvious... but I modified it to be clearer.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian and everyone else; my first attempt ended up being a great opportunity to think about and assess cases. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the background situation that you listened to "Instruments of Ruin" is nicely captured by an ablative absolute.
In addition, I quite like using *nihil nisi* for "nothing but", and it helps keep things more compact as well.

Thus I offer a variant of Sebastian's good answer where he did most of the heavy lifting:

> *Instrumentis Ruinarum auscultatis nihil accepi nisi hanc tunicam.*
> Having listened to Instruments of Ruin I got nothing but this shirt.

Answer (score -2):

I have almost no idea about Latin grammar and very poor Latin vocabulary. To cater these two, there already are 2 beautiful answers but I do have one suggestion to make it a little more catchy. If you interchange the places of 'tunicam' and 'dabar' and print the whole statement in 2 lines like I've shown below, then the rhyme would give a nice and catchy ring to it -

> Ad Instrumenti Ruinarum audiebam
> et solum haec dabar tunicam

My suggestion is using one Latin language rule which is - Word order isn't really important in Latin and the meaning changes only when the ending of word changes.

BTW, this t-shirt is going to be look really cool..

Comment: The two other answers have suggested substantial changes to the phrasing of the question to make it work better both semantically and grammatically. Those changes seem to break your rhymes. Would either of those give a better starting point? I must also add that while word order isn't as important in Latin as in English, it's not irrelevant or completely free either. (I assume these are the reasons why your answer has accumulated a couple of downvotes and flags.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thanks for the useful pointer on word order! Appreciate it