# "Videre" is to "spectare" what "audire" is to...?

Tags: semantics

I am interested, did Latin have a word meaning specifically "*to listen*", as opposed to "*hear*"? Because it did have a word for "*look*" (*spectare*), as opposed to "*see*" (*videre*).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is *auscultō, -āre*, "listen to, pay attention to, give heed to".

Comment: [Related answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/16016/5056) showing the usage of _auscultō, -āre_.

Comment: Lewis and Short on the chronological distribution of *ausculto*: "in the anteclass. per. freq., but not in Lucr.; in the class. per. rare"

Comment: @Herodotean: Interesting that it had declined in frequency in the classical period, but presumably then revived at at some stage, since its descendants are common words in several modern romance languages — *écouter* in French, *ascoltare* in Italian…

Comment: In French we have both *écouter* (listen) and *ausculter* (for a physician: auscultate, examine, listen to the patient's chest)

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: some other ante-classical words also disappear, or almost disappear, during (part of) the classical period only to resurface later. *caballus* comes to mind: it appears in Lucilius, resurfaces in Horace and Petronius, and then of course becomes *cavallo*, *caballo*, and *cheval.*