# Latin verbs describing bodily sensing vs. intellectual sensing

Tags: verbs, word-request

For each of the 5 senses, does Latin have distinct verbs for the intellectual act that follows from the bodily act of sensation?

For example:

| Bodily act of sensing | Corresponding act of intellect |
| --- | --- |
| to look | to see |
| to hear | to listen |

and similarly for the other 3 senses.

<sup>This is reminiscent of St. Augustine's [*De Magistro*](http://www.augustinus.it/latino/maestro/index.htm) V.12, which grapples with [the question of *verbum* ("word") vs. *nomen* ("noun")](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/100716/2014).</sup>

Comment: The verb "teneo" may be used like this.

Comment: You mean like "understand" or "perceive"? Have you thought to just look up translations for those words? Otherwise, what you're asking isn't clear to me.

Comment: @cmw "_Have you thought to just look up translations for those words?_" I understand that "_video_", for example, can encompass both the bodily act of seeing and the intellectual act of perceiving what is seen, but I'm wondering if Latin also has different verbs describing the bodily act and the corresponding intellectual act. See my edits to my question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "corresponding intellectual act". The meanings in the second column are metaphorical -- are you asking whether Latin uses the same metaphors as English?

Comment: I agree with @TKR. I think you're confusing metaphor with some aspect of the verb.

Comment: @cmw In my examples, the verbs in the second column are the figurative sense of the verb in the 1st column; but I'm asking if Latin has two separate, literal sense verbs.

Comment: @TKR When we see something, a body organ (our eyes) interact with light. You can easily look at a picture like [this one](https://photos1.blogger.com/blogger/5639/2020/1600/whatb1.gif), but but you really see (perceive) it (unless I taught you what to look for)? I'm asking if Latin makes a look vs. see distinction (and similarly for the other 4 senses).

Comment: I'm confused by your last comment. It seems to me that you are asking about metaphorical uses of "see", not the distinction between "see" and "look", and similarly for other senses.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta How do you explain the distinction between "see" and "look"?

Comment: @Geremia I'd say that looking means pointing your eyes at something, and seeing means noticing or becoming aware of something that you are looking at. While seeing does involve the brain, it is about the brain interpreting what the eye sees. In phrases like "I see your point" the meaning is different, as it is not about actually perceiving something through vision. The verb "see" is used metaphorically. The question as it now stands is about the literal/metaphorical distinction, not about the look/see (or listen/hear or any other) distinction.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thanks for the clarification. I'm not wanting to speak of metaphors; my examples weren't correct. I've edited my question.

Comment: @Geremia Excellent! Much clearer now. Now I, and judging by the comments and votes, others understand what you are after. Take a look at [this question on the hear/listen distinction](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/20599/79). Does it answer your question?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Very similar, but I'd like to know the pairs for all 5 senses, if they exist.